# How to return vector from C++ function and read using Python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11, ctypes

I'm having a C++ function which is returning of type vector.

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> exampleFunction() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    # intermediate code
    return vec;
}
```

Now I need to call this function exampleFunction after importing the C++ built file.
The return of exampleFunction, vector I need to access.
I tried defining the structure like below in Python

```
class tempStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vec", POINTER(c_char_p)]
```

but this is not helping me to get the full vector array. With this, I'm able to access only the first item of the vector through this.
How to access the full array?

Comment: To be honest, I'm impressed that you got that much. Most of the time other programming languages have no clue what the memory layout of an object looks like. `Std::vector` is typically three pointers and the actual data  it contains can be found elsewhere at one of those pointers (and the others point to the end of the data and the end of the allocation). `std::string` could be a pointer to a `char` buffer and a length, but usually they're a pointer to the buffer, an array to use as the buffer if the contained  string is short, the length, and some extra book-keeping for other tricks.

Comment: You pass one of those suckers even to a program from a different C++ compiler/ library implementation and the `vector` or `string` is meaningless if not instantly fatal.

Comment: Typically you fall back on serializing the data or converting it to what we used to call Plain Old Data. Basically C-Style arrays of simple types. Here you would probably return a pointer to an array of pointers to `char` arrays that hold the string data. Remember to make sure all of this stuff stays in scope until the python code is done with it.

Comment: You won’t do this with `ctypes` it’s called C types for a reason

Comment: Passing data from native C++ code to python (a managed environment) requires marshaling. Usually it is easier to do when the memory for the data is allocated on the caller's side. This can be done by splitting an API into 2 parts: GetResultSize(...) should return the size of the memory, then allocate it on the client side, and pass to GetResultData(...). A pointer to managed memory can be passed into the C++ call and be filled there.